# Automatically choose servername in vim

Tags: linux, vim, callback

Is there a way to automatically start text-mode vim with servername chosen dynamically?

clientserver support allows vim to receive callbacks. Once it is compiled with clientserver enabled, I must start vim with a chosen servername like so for servername FOO:

```
vim --servername FOO
```

This must be done with a different name for each invocation of vim, so simple aliasing in bashrc is wrong as far as I understand.

Comment: This is not a programming question, thus off-topic here; it should better be asked over at https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ok. Should I delete it, or move it? The answer below actually answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

From `:help client-server-name`:

> If the specified name is not available, a postfix is applied until a free name is encountered, i.e. "gvim1" for the second invocation of gvim on a particular X-server.

So starting several Vim sessions with `--servername FOO` will result in several servers named `FOO`, `FOO1`, `FOO2`, etc.